# How to teach yourself physics systematically？

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

I'm just a university student and I am not physics majors, but I am interested in physics. I plan to self-taught physics. However I don't know how to teach yourself physics systematically. I want to know what math I need to learn, what is the order of learning, which textbooks are recommended？

Comment: It is not a good idea to self-teach physics. Since you are still in university and you are interested in physics attend a proper course on it.

Comment: @flippiefanus Why is it not a good idea, pray tell? Unfortunately, in poorer countries where academia and research infrastructure isn't top-notch, one is often forced to major in subjects that bring-in financial security. One may not have the liberty to take a physics course in universities in such places, where curricula may often be rigid or there may not even be a department for it. What must the interested student do then?

Comment: @inspire kindly refocus the question to ask something specific. You ask too many questions.

Comment: Then you need to do what I did. First do the degree that will bring in the bacon and then afterward do physics. However, I found that if one is passionate about something, it will bring in the bacon anyway.

Comment: My focus is on what math I need to learn to be able to teach myself in undergraduate-level physics, and then what physics knowledge should be learned first and what to learn later

Answer (score 2):

At my university (MIPT) there are the subjects and plans for them:

1st semester:

-General physics: mechanics - https://pastebin.com/UgHnVtaY

-Introduction to Mathematical Analysis - https://pastebin.com/fkbPuC36

-Analytical geometry - https://pastebin.com/MKyniqtS

2nd semester:

-Multidimensional analysis, integrals and series - https://pastebin.com/B7wxbMnp

-Linear algebra - https://pastebin.com/H3ZBp3uT

-General Physics: thermodynamics and molecular physics - https://pastebin.com/C9YHeEnC

I think it will be enough for you now, if you can handle it then come here again. Any complex math from list above is not necessary for general physics in first semesters but linear algebra and special functions for example will be necessary in quantum mechanics in 3rd year and later if you'll decide to study physics seriously. I am sorry that I can't suggest any literature but I am studying in another language so my materials will be useless for you